# Устройство не отображается в списке подключённых ADB

Tags: android, windows-10, adb

Пишу автокликер, эмулирующий нажатия через adb shell input. Всё было в порядке, пока я не установил adb в Termux и не подключил устройство к самому себе, чтобы можно было запускать приложение почти без участия компьютера. После перезагрузки устройства, телефон перестал отображаться при подключении к компьютеру, тогда помог способ с отключением и прописыванием adb kill-server. Позже я несколько раз перезагружал телефон, нужно было лишь включать отладку по сети с компьютера. Теперь же, на телефоне закончилась зарядка с включенным кликером и его опять не стало в списке подключенных на компьютере. При этом, в списке уведомлений на телефоне отображается, что отладка по usb включена. Android 10

[image: Отладка включена]

Методы, которые я пробовал:

1. Предыдущий метод с остановкой процесса adb не помог
2. Установка google usb драйвера
3. Использование другой версии ADB
4. Переключение MTP/PTP
5. Перезагрузка
6. Сброс списка подтверждённых устройств, включение/выключение отладки

Возможно, есть что-то ещё, но я уже, если честно, забыл

[image: Устройства нет в списке подключённых]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Телефон по умолчанию подключается к текущему ADB серверу , не указывайте путь до .exe попробуйте просто указать команду adb devices. В случае если у вас данная команда не отображается, вам следует указать в PATH путь до adb и он будет использоваться по умолчанию.

Comment: Я вообще пропустил факт того, что adb могут блокировать друг друга. Спасибо Вам большое, Вы меня спасли